# Is it possible to get signins via API for Azure AD Basic EDU license in Microsoft azure api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How to fetch siginins (login information) for all the users in domain with the basic license without AAD premium licenses ]

Comment: I have tried the below api's which requires AAD Premium license   
  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns 
 https://graph.windows.net/domain/activities/signinEvents

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft Graph Explorer to get sign-ins information for all users by using:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports//getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='{period_value}')`

or `GET https:/graph.microsoft.com/v1.o/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(date={date_value})`

And the required related permissions :
[image]
For the details, you could read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getteamsuseractivityuserdetail).

Comment: The above api gives the information about the last activity for an entity as this [Report Refresh Date,User Principal Name,Last Activity Date,Is Deleted,Deleted Date,Assigned Products,Team Chat Message Count,Private Chat Message Count,Call Count,Meeting Count,Has Other Action,Report Period] .  I need the information like location,ip, device Information etc for a particular user